# Using find command to delete multiple extensions older than certaint time

Tags: linux, shell, find

I had a question using the "-o" option in find to find multiple extensions.

```
find "DIRECTORY" -type f -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.html -mtime +95
```

In the above I want to delete all files of two extensions that are older than a certain time.
By using `-o` to list multiple names, does the `-mtime` only apply to the second or are older jpgs also excluded?

Thanks

Comment: Don't know, put brackets around the or then it will be ok whichever way, `find "DIRECTORY" -type f \( -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.html \) -mtime +95`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can solve this with parentheses:

```
find "DIRECTORY" -type f \( -name \*.jpg -o -name \*.html \) -mtime +95
```

`find` operators are evaluated in order of precedence. From the manual:

```
 ( expr )
          Force precedence.  Since parentheses are special  to  the  shell,
          you  will  normally  need to quote them.  Many of the examples in
          this manual page use  backslashes  for  this  purpose:  `\(...\)'
          instead of `(...)'.

 expr1 expr2
          Two expressions in a row are taken to be joined with  an  implied
          "and"; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is false.

 expr1 -o expr2
          Or; expr2 is not evaluated if expr1 is true.
```

Answer (score 0):

It only applies to second argument, just did a manual check real fast